# only keep rows with values greater than something

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, string-length

I want to modify a dataset such that it should check all rows of a column 'Column'. Each row has a string value. I want to discard the rows where the length of the string is less than 3. This works if I want to discard all rows where the value is 9.

```
modifiedDf = modifiedDf[modifiedDf['Column'] != "9"]
```

But if I change it for eg,

```
modifiedDf = modifiedDf[len(modifiedDf['Column']) > 3]
```

it just gives me a keyError: true.

**Edit:**

Is it possible to check the length of only some rows? For instance, I have another col `Class`. I want to check the 'Col' for all rows where the Class is 'Marke'.

Basically, I want to leave the remaining rows as they are and only filter out rows where the Col length < 3 if and only if the Class value for that row is marke. If class value is not marke, the rows should remain the same even if Len < 3.

```
mask = modifiedDf['Class'] == "Marke"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two conditions in your indexer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column': ['aa', 'asdfdsf', 'bb', 'sdfdsss', 'aa', 'a'],
                   'Class': ['Marke']*4 + ['Other']*2},)


df = df[~((df['Class']=='Marke') & (df['Column'].str.len() < 3))]
```

Answer (score -1):

`len(modifiedDf['Column'])` is equal to `len(modifiedDf)`, so `len(modifiedDf['Column']) > 3` is most likely `True`, which gives you the error since `modifiedDf[True]` tries to access column named `True`.

I think you want

```
modifiedDf = modifiedDf[modifiedDf['Column'].str.len() > 3]
```

Comment: This doesn't address the 'Class' filter.